# Is dihedral group of order $2n$ a subgroup of group of permutations on $n$ symbols, $n$ greater than or equal to $3?$

Tags: group-theory

To me, it looks like dihedral group of order $2n$ contains permutations on $n$ symbols, not all but some particular. Also the operation in both groups is function composition. So, I feel $D(2n)$ is subgroup of $S(n)$. Am I right? Please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is this true, it's true for every finite group. Every group has a group multiplication table, which can be thought of as an action of the group on itself corresponding to certain permutations.

The precise statement is called [Cayley's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem).

Actually, the link here says that it is true for any group at all, which is news to me, but even better. The link contains a proof of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

The dihedral group is the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon.
If you label the vertices with numbers $1,\ldots,n$, each symmetry
corresponds to a permutation of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, that is,
an element of $S_n$. This gives a representation of the dihedral
group as a subgroup of $S_n$.

Comment: The dihedral group $D_n$ generally denotes the symmetries of an $n$-gon; OP wrote $D(2n)$, which seems to indicate a $2n$-gon (and which makes the question more interesting). Then again, OP also said "the group of *order* $2n$", which may be what was actually intended (and for which your answer is correct, but for which I find the question less interesting).

Comment: @JohnHughes I denote the symmetry group of the pentagon as $D_5$, but many do denote it as $D_{10}$.

Comment: Understood ... I'm just not sure what the OP meant!